# Can't search in Windows 10, need to login

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 is requiring me to log in to "Search the web and Windows." I am absolutely certain my username and password are correct as I have just reset them both.

After logging in (which took about 10 tries because every time I tabbed to the password line the window would disappear), I was prompted to enter my "old" Windows password.

I don't know what that means because I entered all the passwords I've ever used for Windows and it would not accept any of them.  There is no "forgot password" option and you cannot get past this window - I just keep getting redirected back to the first page.

I was simply trying to use the search function to complete a project I am working on but have instead been stuck trying to log in for almost 30 minutes.

Comment: To do anything in Windows, you must be logged in, so what is prompting you when you do a search?  Can you get a screenshot?

Comment: You have my sympathies. I can't help, but it's frustrations like that which lead people to [jump ship to linux](http://www.linuxmint.com) ;-)

Comment: This is a bug. We've had this happen to a few engineers in our shop. I'm guessing that this was an upgrade rather than a new install. For me I reboot and it works again. Another engineer wiped his machine and did a fresh install.